# pyVisa TypeError after applying folder structure

Tags: python, pyvisa

Im using pyVisa to communicate with an OSA. After i move the files in folders to have a better structure, nothing works anymore. 
The structure is: 
ProjektFolder -> Includes -> VisaInstrument.py and ProjektFolder -> Instrument -> osa.py

In VisaInstrument.py the code is like this:

```
import pyvisa
...
class VisaInstrument():

    def __init__(self, resource):
         self.rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
         self.resource = resource
         self.instr = self.rm.open_resource(self.resource)
         logging.debug('New lab object (resource %s) created.' % self.resource)
```

and in osa.py

```
from Includes import VisaInstrument
...
class osa(VisaInstrument.VisaInstrument):


    def __init__(self, resource):
        VisaInstrument.__init__(self, resource)
```

When i try to initialize the osa like this (in a different file):

```
from Instrument import osa
osaControl = osa.osa('GPIB0::14::INSTR')
```

i get following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "C:\python\ProjektFolder\Instrument\osa.py", line 40, in **init**
>
> VisaInstrument.**init**(self, resource)
>
> TypeError: module() argument 1 must be str, not osa

With init as show in code not **bold**

can anyone tell me whats my mistake here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: i didnt call VisaInstrument properly in class osa

```
from Includes import VisaInstrument
...
class osa(VisaInstrument.VisaInstrument):


    def __init__(self, resource):
        VisaInstrument.VisaInstrument.__init__(self, resource)
             ^this was missing
```